# Carbon setLocale not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Ive read several stackoverflows about set locale. I tested locale -a in the terminal to see if my locale was in there, and it was. The following rule of code is added in the appServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    Carbon::setLocale($this->app->getLocale());
}
```

The $this->app->getLocale() returns "nl"

Anyone know why Carbon still shows Sunday instead of Zondag for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to use `setLocale(LC_TIME, $this->app->getLocale())` somewhere at the start of your application.

Then if you wish to have the localized date format with local names use the `formatLocalized` function

```
Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php for parameter for formatting

Comment: {{$var->start_at->formatLocalized('d-m-Y')}} that doesnt seem to work, it just echo's d-m-y as a string

Comment: did you add the LC_TIME setting before running that template?

Comment: It's in my appserviceprovider, so yea the command should run while the app starts

Comment: oh wait, formatLocalized uses a different format. Try `%d %B %Y`

Comment: It seems the problem was Carbon::setLocale, when i used just setLocale it worked, thanks! was reading over it in your post

Comment: formatLocalized() is not working now since PHP 8, use translatedFormat() instead

Answer (score 30):

**Translating a carbon date using global localized format**

Tested in: Laravel 5.8, Laravel 6, Laravel 8

---

In config/app.php

```
'locale' => 'id', // The default is 'en', but this time I want localize them to Indonesian (ID)
```

Then, to make locale output do something like this:

```
// WITHOUT LOCALE
Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-03-01')->format('d F Y'); //Output: "01 March 2019"
now()->subMinute(5)->diffForHumans(); // Output: "5 minutes ago"

// WITH LOCALE
Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-03-01')->translatedFormat('d F Y'); // Output: "01 Maret 2019"
now()->subMinute(5)->diffForHumans(); // Output: "5 menit yang lalu"
```

For more information about converting localize dates you can see on below link
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Comment: This should be used for Laravel 8

Comment: Note that if you use Laravel 5.5+, the locale will be automatically set according to current last App:setLocale execution. So `diffForHumans`, `isoFormat`, `translatedFormat` and localized properties such as `->dayName` or `->monthName` will be localized transparently.

Answer (score 3):

Researching I have found two alternative options:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$date->locale('de')->translatedFormat('d F Y');
```

and:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$carbonDateFactory = new CarbonFactory([
  'locale' => 'de_DE',
  'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
]);
$carbonDateFactory->make($date)->isoFormat('d MMMM YYYY');
```

and the ISO compatible format symbols are [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/)

Answer (score 1):

In your AppServiceProvider's register function:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL.utf8');
Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
```

Then use **translatedFormat()** instead of format() or formatLocalized() which is deprecated.

This uses the date() patern which works like format() but translates the string using the current locale.

read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by calling `setLocale` on multiple classes:

```
$locale = 'nl_NL';
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale($locale);
\Carbon\CarbonImmutable::setLocale($locale);
\Carbon\CarbonPeriod::setLocale($locale);
\Carbon\CarbonInterval::setLocale($locale);
\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::setLocale($locale);
```

There's also [this ServiceProvider](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php) that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you use newer version of Laravel with php8+ and Carbon 2 and use UTC as default timezone (like they suggest) you will encounter some issues using translatedFormat as it's not gonna convert hours.

Here is a suggestion, i use a Carbon macro to simplify. In AppServiceProvider.php boot method, you should add this (using french locale) :

```php
        //set defaults for Carbon --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        setlocale(LC_TIME, app()->getLocale());
        date_default_timezone_set(config('app.timezone'));
        Carbon::setLocale(app()->getLocale());
        //for displaying dates with good timezone translation, we force to french !
        $userSettings = [
            'locale' => 'fr',
            'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
            'format' => 'd M Y H:i'
        ];
        //register a macro to be a shortcut for displaying dates !

        Carbon::macro('display', function () use ($userSettings) {
            return $this->copy()->locale($userSettings['locale'])->tz($userSettings['timezone'])->translatedFormat($userSettings['format']);
        });
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- set defaults for Carbon
```

Then when you work with a Carbon UTC date (as this is the default timezone), you can use the macro to convert it to your locale and timezone before calling translatedFormat. Example in a blade file where $message->created_at is my Carbon date.

```php
<div class="fs-6 text-muted">{{$message->created_at->display()}}</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this : setLocale(LC_TIME, app()->getLocale());

Comment: The correct answer was given months ago. There is no need to repeat it.